# How to prepare users password for firebase importUsers?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I have a large json file with all my previous users. I need to prepare them to be imported. I keep getting this error : *Error 4  failed to import:  FirebaseAuthError: The password hash must be a valid byte buffer.*

What is the proper way to store a hashed password as byte buffer in a json?

```
var jsonFile = require('./users.json');
var fs = require('fs')

let newArr = []

jsonFile.file.slice(0, 5).map( val => {
    newArr.push({
        uid: val.id,
        email: val.email,
        passwordHash: Buffer.from(val.password) // val.password is hashed
    })
})

let data = JSON.stringify(newArr);
fs.writeFileSync('newArr.json', data);
```

In my main import file

```
var jsonFile = require('./newArr.json');

// I was testing it like that and everything is working fine.
const userImportRecords = [
    {
        uid: '555555555555',
        email: 'user@example.com',
        passwordHash: Buffer.from('$2a$10$P6TOqRVAXL2FLRzq9Ii6AeGqzV4mX8UNdpHvlLr.4DPxq2Xsd54KK')
    }
];

admin.auth().importUsers(jsonFile, {
  hash: {
    algorithm: 'BCRYPT',
    rounds: 10
  }
})
```

Comment: Firebase uses *MD5* in 2020 for hashing passwords? You're using Bcrypt here which is what you should be doing. How does MD5 factor in?

Comment: My old passwords are encoded with bcrypt round 10. md5 is not important sorry. I should have said : hashed password

Comment: Are you sure `val.password` exists? It's worth testing what's in `val` or showing us an example. It may differ structurally from your second example.

Comment: Yes it a contains exactly $2a$10$P6TOqRVAXL2FLRzq9Ii6AeGqzV4mX8UNdpHvlLr.4DPxq2Xsd54KK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to this problem. I'm parsing users.json directly inside the importUsers() file. Since I don't have to store the Buffer inside a json file again, the passwordHash stay a buffer.

This is the right way to do it

```
let newArr = []

jsonFile.file.slice(0, 5).map( val => {
    newArr.push({
        uid: val.id,
        email: val.email,
        passwordHash: Buffer.from(val.password)
    })
})

admin.auth().importUsers(newArr, {
  hash: {
    algorithm: 'BCRYPT',
    rounds: 10
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first code snippet writes `Buffer` values to the file system. This doesn't work the way you expect. For instance, try running the following example:

```
const val = {uid: 'test', passwordHash: Buffer.from('test')};
fs.writeFileSync('newArr.json', JSON.stringify(val));
```

The resulting file will contain the following text:

```
{"uid":"test","passwordHash":{"type":"Buffer","data":[116,101,115,116]}}
```

When you `require()` this file, the `passwordHash` gets assigned to the object `{ type: 'Buffer', data: [ 116, 101, 115, 116 ] }`. That's not the `Buffer` type expected by the `importUsers()` API.

I believe your `newArr` variable contains the right kind of array that can be passed into `importUsers()`. But writing it to the file system, and then reloading it changes the type of all `Buffer` fields.

Comment: What's the right way to import users with a passwordHash from a json file?